# Azure Recovery Vault and regions

Tags: azure, azure-site-recovery

I'm confused about Azure Recovery vaults and regions

In https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-vms-prepare it says
"You can only select VMs in the same region as the vault."

In
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-create-recovery-services-vault#set-cross-region-restore

It states "the Cross Region Restore option allows you to restore data in a secondary, Azure paired region"

That's for restoring, not backing up

Asking Gemini/Chatgpt and they both answer "No, an Azure VM does not have to be in the same region as Azure Recovery Vault to use it"

I'm obviously missing some documentation here, or misunderstanding it

Comment: The statement "You can only select VMs in the same region as the vault" in the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-vms-prepare is correct. However, the statement "No, an Azure VM does not have to be in the same region as Azure Recovery Vault to use it" provided by Gemini/Chatgpt is incorrect. Azure VMs must be in the same region as the Recovery Services vault to use it for backup and restore operations.

Comment: The Cross Region Restore option mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-create-recovery-services-vault#set-cross-region-restore is used for restoring data in a secondary, Azure paired region. This feature is only available for Recovery Services vaults that use the GRS replication type.

Comment: To summarize, Azure VMs must be in the same region as the Recovery Services vault to use it for backup and restore operations. The Cross Region Restore option is used for restoring data in a secondary, Azure paired region and is only available for Recovery Services vaults that use the GRS replication type.

Comment: I think what @Arko wrote should be the answer here.

Comment: Thanks @KonTheCat, I'll post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement "You can only select VMs in the same region as the vault" in the document  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-vms-prepare  is correct. However, the statement "No, an Azure VM does not have to be in the same region as Azure Recovery Vault to use it" provided by Gemini/Chatgpt is incorrect. Azure VMs must be in the same region as the Recovery Services vault to use it for backup and restore operations.

The Cross Region Restore option mentioned in  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-create-recovery-services-vault#set-cross-region-restore  is used for restoring data in a secondary, Azure paired region. This feature is only available for Recovery Services vaults that use the GRS replication type.

To summarize, Azure VMs must be in the same region as the Recovery Services vault to use it for backup and restore operations. The [Cross Region Restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-create-recovery-services-vault#set-cross-region-restore)  (CRR) option is used for restoring data in a secondary, Azure paired region and is only available for Recovery Services vaults that use the GRS replication type.
i.e.

- **For Backup**: VMs must be in the same region as the Recovery Services vault.
- **For Restore**: The CRR feature facilitates data restoration in a secondary region, exclusively available to vaults with GRS configuration.

References:

- [Create and configure a Recovery Services vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-create-recovery-services-vault#set-cross-region-restore)
- [How to restore Azure VM data in Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-restore-vms#cross-region-restore)
- [Recovery Services vaults overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-recovery-services-vault-overview#key-features)
- [Back up Azure VMs in a Recovery Services vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-arm-vms-prepare)

Comment: https://4sysops.com/archives/azure-recovery-services-vault-ironing-out-the-confusion/
This suggests that Azure VMs must be in the same region, but on premises VMs don't have to be. That may be where the confusion comes from